# ListView modified from outside source before submit

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

I have a list view that contains for this example lets say 5 rows. The list view is in a form and has a AjaxSubmitLink for deletion of a row.

The data that loads comes from a loadable detachable model that loads rows from a database.

User A: Renders the list loading all 5 rows with delete buttons.

User B: On another machine loads the same list and deletes row 3.

User A: Still sees all 5 rows and deletes row 4. The model reattaches and instead of row 4 being deleted row 5 is deleted.

```
Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");
form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(form);

ListView<Data> list = new ListView<Data>("list", detachableDataList)
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Data> item)
        {
            AjaxSubmitLink delete = new AjaxSubmitLink("delete")
            {
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
                {
                    Data data = item.getModelObject();
                    DB.delete(data.getPk());
                    target.add(form);
                }
            }
        }
}
form.add(list);
```

Attempted to try using setReuseItems(true)
Attempted to use a RefreshingView
Attempted to override getListItemModel

None of these worked

**EDIT For Attempted Clarity**

```
Item 1 [delete]
Item 2 [delete]
Item 3 [delete]
Item 4 [delete]
Item 5 [delete]
```

When I click delete on Item 4 it applies to Item 5 since Item 3 was deleted by another user.

Comment: If data comes from a DB, you should an unique id, which makes it easy to identify the item. If you try to delete an item by its id, and the DB reports the id missing, you can assume that another user already deleted it and notify the current user of this? `if (DB.delete(id)) { success("deleted"); }else { ldm.detach(); error("already gone");} target.add(form);`

Comment: The problem is the wrong id comes back. In my example you click item 4 and get the id of item 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `Data`, so use it.

```
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Data> item)
    {
        Data data = item.getModelObject();
        final Serializable id = data.getId(); // the primary key
        AjaxSubmitLink delete = new AjaxSubmitLink("delete")
        {
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
            {
                DB.delete(id);
                target.add(form);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you added is what I am essentially doing I just left that part out. The problem is that the database loses a row between the render and submit when a different user deletes a row from the database. My list view is then off by one and when the delete is clicked the row with the same index now has a different model object since the model reattaches.

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer by changing `id` with `primaryKey`. The records in the DB have primary keys, right?

Comment: The id vs primary key distinction here is irrelevant I think. I don't understand how this solves the problem of the model object changing between render and the click. Data data = item.getModelObject returns the wrong data.

Comment: I understand you now. Please see the final update. It keeps a reference to the data's id that is used later.

Comment: This should work, ListItem will no longer need to be final though and Serializable id does.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to override `getListItemModel`?

```
protected IModel<T> getListItemModel(final IModel<? extends List<T>> listViewModel,
        final int index)
{
    // Change the line below to track your model by a Pk or Id instead of index
    return new ListItemModel<T>(this, index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the Data object when the list is rendered instead of getting it when the users clicks delete

```
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Data> item)
    {
        final Data data = item.getModelObject();
        AjaxSubmitLink delete = new AjaxSubmitLink("delete")
        {
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
            {                
                DB.delete(data.getId());
                target.add(form);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This may be what I need to do. I just was hoping the other pieces of the data object would change organically if modified. Using this prevents that I believe.